# 「いくらか」と「若干」の使い分けを教えていただけないでしょうか。

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words, usage, word-usage

「いくらか」と「若干」の違いは何ですか。ただ「いくらか」は話し言葉で「若干」は書き言葉ですか。正しいですか。もし、正しかったら、他の違いがありますか。

Comment: Aside from an oral vs. written distinction, another difference is that whereas いくらか indicates a low amount, the emphasis of 若干 is on the existence of an amount, though low. Most occurrences of 若干 should be able to be replaced with いくらか, but perhaps not vice versa.

Comment: I know people who have used 若干 as part of their vocal repertoire. So much so that it became part of mine: 「Q お仲すいた？」「A んんん、若干...」.　I wouldn't draw such a distinction between written and spoken. 幾らか implies an undisclosed quantity (some), usually not too small. 若干 implies a minimal amount, usually unquantifiable, or used colloquially to mean 'a bit', 'a smidge', etc.

Comment: There is no difference, they are synonymous. 
https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/10685/meaning/m0u/ 
https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/102360/meaning/m0u/